# Creating hyperlink to a sheet using excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column which has values A, B, and C in a Sheet called *Demo*. There are other three sheets with the same name as the column values. I want to create a hyperlink using excel formula which would refer to the sheets A, B, and C.
I tried with this `=HYPERLINK("#'"&A2&"'!A2","Link")`
But this would have another column which will have a friendly name as Link.
Is it possible to refer to the same values without using any other column in Sheet Demo?

Comment: If I understood well, you wish that cells could contain both a hyperlink formula and a value. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Well I tought you could not. BUT you can, as long as you can nest the value (or the equation/formula producing this value) into the friendly name. Without quotes.

Comment: do you mean something like `=HYPERLINK("#'"&A2&"'!A2","Link to "&A2)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Exactly what I ended up doing now. Thanks! Additionally, we have to turn on the iterative calculation from File->Options->Formula->Check the box having label Enable iterative calculation so that it can understand it's a circular reference.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Either you or the OP can post that as answer to guide others that might stumble on this exact same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Although, I think it is worth considering VBA too (since you included that tag in your original question).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo restoreevents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim sn As String: Const hf As String = "=HYPERLINK(""#'{ref}'!A2"",""{ref}"")"
    With Me
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("A2:A4")) Is Nothing _
        And Len(Target.Value2) <> 0 Then
            sn = Target.Value2
            Application.Undo
            Target.Formula = Replace(hf, "{ref}", sn)
        End If
    End With

restoreevents:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Above code will hyperlink using formula once you type the Sheet name on the target ranges.